# Navigation undefined - TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm facing problem using navigation prop for the header button on the Home screen. It seems the problem is the Navaigation prop can't be rendered. Can someone help me clear this issue? I spent some good amount of time reading the document, but can't go further. Thanks!

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Home from '../screens/Shop/Home';
import ProductDetails from '../screens/Shop/ProductDetails';
import Colors from '../constants/Colors';
import {Ionicons} from '@expo/vector-icons';
import {
  HeaderButtons,
  HeaderButton,
  Item,
} from 'react-navigation-header-buttons';
import Cart from '../screens/Shop/Cart';
import {NavigationContainer, useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';

const IoniconsHeaderButton = (props) => (
  <HeaderButton
    IconComponent={Ionicons}
    iconSize={23}
    color="white"
    {...props}
  />
);

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default ShopNavigator = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: Colors.accent,
        },
        headerTintColor: 'white',
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontFamily: 'balsamiq-regular',
        },
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          headerRight: () => (
            <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={IoniconsHeaderButton}>
              <Item
                title="search"
                iconName="cart-outline"
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Cart')}
              />
            </HeaderButtons>
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="ProductDetails"
        component={ProductDetails}
        options={({route}) => ({title: route.params.itemTitle})}
      />
      <Stack.Screen name="Cart" component={Cart} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you are just not passing the navigation params that is returned by options. That's why the undefined error is coming

Change this

```
  options={{
          headerRight: () => (
            <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={IoniconsHeaderButton}>
              <Item
                title="search"
                iconName="cart-outline"
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Cart')}
              />
            </HeaderButtons>
          ),
        }}
```

to this

```
   options={({ navigation }) => ({
        headerRight: () => (
          <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={IoniconsHeaderButton}>
            <Item
              title="search"
              iconName="cart-outline"
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Cart')}
            />
          </HeaderButtons>
        ),
      })}
```